# Angular / Rxjs - queuing / blocking HTTP requests until a previous request completes

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am talking to an API server that uses single-use auth tokens which are re-issued (i.e. a new token is generated) every request. If two API requests are issued at the same time using the same token, one fails due to an expired token and error handlers can be triggered unnecessarily.

What I would like to do is build in a waiting mechanism so only one HTTP request is issued at a time, and subsequent requests are queued until the previous ones are completed.

I would like to build this in a generic way so I can have one service layer to issue requests with so it is transparent to the upper layers however I am struggling to find a neat way to do this. Any suggestions?

`-- edit --`

I should have mentioned that all subsequent API call URLs / request bodies depend directly on the response of the previous API call, e.g. `GET /books?apiKey=ABC` returns:

`{
  'apiKey': 'XYZ',
  'names': [...]
}`

The next request that was queued must wait for this response and append the new apiKey: `GET /authors?apiKey=XYZ`

In the above example, performing `GET /authors?apiKey=ABC` would 
result in an error.

If there is a strong dependence between two HTTP requests (e.g. request book, then request authors for that particular book based on its id), they can be serialised using a flatMap, nested subscriptions etc. I need similar functionality to this but in a generic way where I can add requests onto a queue that is serialised at runtime.

`-- edit two --`

I have two components like the following, lets say both call an API call on startup.

```
class ComponentA { 
    ngOnInit(api:<BookApi extends CommonApi>) {
        this.api.list().subscribe(x => {...});
    }
}

class ComponentB { 
    ngOnInit(api:<CityLookupApi extends CommonApi>) {
        this.api.list().subscribe(x => {...});
    }
}
```

All the API services extend a common API to hide the apiKey handling behind it so the components can use a higher level call to aid comprehension. The issue is that if the components both are initialised at near the same time, both calls can use the same api key and one will fail. However, I cannot create these Observable batches up front using e.g. forkJoin as they are created and subscribed to asynchronously at run-time as they are created in their separate components.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `Observable.concat(...myArrayOfAjaxRequestObservable)` to have each observable consumed one by one.

Only Observable.contact have to subscribe himself to your ajax request. Is is only way to be 100% sure request will not be trigger by another part of your code.

more information here : https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/concat.html

---UPDATE---

Sample : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-66ic6c?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: This is probably the way to go for the OP. I've added the exhaustMap answer as an alternative solution for some edge cases. Have an upvote :)

Comment: hi @TomaszKula i am not sure to understand why we need `exhaustMap` with Observable.concat. As you can see on my attached sample, all request are consuming step by step and everything is block until current answer is not received.

Comment: We do not need it with .concat. It is one or the other. It's an alternative solution.

Comment: Ok, nice clarification and happy coding.

Comment: This doesn't seem quite like what I need. This will queue up requests and wait for responses one by one, but it still issues all requests at the same time. I changed your sample to append an apiKey parameter based on the 'seed' in the API response. If you check the network tab, it will show that all the requests use the same key instead of waiting for a response to insert the new seed/key before it fires the next request: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sx4zxx?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: as recommanded by @TomaszKula you can use `switchMap` or `exhaustMap` brief proof of concept here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pmpacp?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thanks @Yanis-git. It's still slightly different to my use case as I want to add to the queue even after the observable is subscribed to. I will expand my question to give an example - I am probably thinking about this with the wrong approach though as it seems needlessly complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Yanis-git answers the queuing problem. If you want to block all the request while the other request is happening, use `exhaustMap`.

[exhaustmap docs](https://github.com/btroncone/learn-rxjs/blob/master/operators/transformation/exhaustmap.md)

Answer (score 1):

I would consider to use `mergeMap` together with its `concurrency` parameter.

This is a snippet of code  that simulates what I intend

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs';

const requestsRemoteService = new Subject<string>();
const requestStream = requestsRemoteService.asObservable();

// this function simulates the execution of the request
const requestExecution = (input: string) => {
    return Observable.of(input + ' executed').delay(2000);
}

// this is what the service should to queue the requests
requestStream
// the last parameter, set to 1, is the level of concurrency
.mergeMap(requestInput => requestExecution(requestInput), 1)
.subscribe(
    data => console.log(data),
    err => console.error(err),
    () => console.log('DONE')
)

// these are the various requests coming to the service
setTimeout(() => requestsRemoteService.next('First request'), 1);
setTimeout(() => requestsRemoteService.next('Second request'), 2);
setTimeout(() => requestsRemoteService.next('Third request'), 3);
```